# Firebase dynamic links always opens App Store even the app is installed

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, firebase-dynamic-links

I have used firebase dynamic links [package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links#:%7E:text=A%20Flutter%20plugin%20to%20use,content%20in%20your%20native%20app.) to implement firebase dynamic links to my App, Android it working as expected but when open it from iphone link always redirect to app store,I have followed below step by step  article for Ios implementation
[step by step medium article by Dominik Keller](https://medium.com/dev-genius/firebase-flutter-dynamic-links-step-by-step-guide-630402ee729b)

This is the payload I used to create firebase dynamic links

```
{
 "dynamicLinkInfo":{
 "domainUriPrefix":"https://test.page.link",
 "link":"https://test.com?test=test",
 "androidInfo":{
  "androidPackageName":"test"
  },
  "iosInfo": {
   "iosBundleId":"test",
  "iosAppStoreId":"test"
  },
  "navigationInfo": {
   "enableForcedRedirect":false
  }
 },
"suffix": {"option": "SHORT"}
}
```

I have used My real values Instead of test

Comment: Any solution, I'm getting same issue.